# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlemaps' - though googlemaps installed

Tags: python, google-maps, package

I am running an app.py which imports googlemaps as

```
import googlemaps
```

But when I do a pip list, it lists googlemaps as

```
googlemaps      3.0.2
```

When I run the app,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "app.py", line 40, in <module>
    import googlemaps
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlemaps'
```

I am on Windows, Python 3.6.0

Comment: did my answer help?
What was the problem finally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be sure. that pip and your script use the same python version I suggest to call following commands from the same terminal window.

```
python3 -m pip freeze | grep -i googlemaps
python3 -c "import sys ; print(sys.exewutable)"
python3 -c "import sys ; print("\n".join(sys.path))"
```

Try even following line to prove that `googlemaps` is installed if not being called from your app

```
python3 -c "import googlemaps"
```

and

```
python3 app.py
```

If you do not call your app directly with python, then tell us how you start the app. This different way of calling might be why it is not pointing to the same python version / virtualenv than the one where you installed `googlemaps`

If you do not know how the app is exactly started (e.g. started by a web server or similar), then I suggest you add following lines to `app.py`
before the import line that fails.

```
import os, sys
# the next two l
with open(os.expanduser("~/debug.txt", "w") as fout:
    fout.write("EXE: %s\n" % sys.executable)
    fout.write("PATH:\n" + ("\n".join(sys.path)))
```

This should create a file named `debug.txt`,
that you can inspect

Comment: Figured out that I had two different verions of python running and py command was not using the version I wanted. Your clue helped. Thanks!